# jQuery not working for new items

Tags: jquery, dynamic, hover

Hello I want to hide/show the rows of a table on hover. The problem is that query is not working on newly dynamically added elements..

```
<button id="myButton">Add New Row</button>
<br/>
<br/>

<br/>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>This is a static row.</td>
    </tr>
</table>



$("#myButton").click(function () {

   var newRow = '<tr><td>This is a dynamically added row.</td></tr>'; 
    $('#myTable').append(newRow);
});



 $('#myTable tr').hover(

       function() {
       $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 1);

     },
     function() {

         $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1);
     }

    );
```

here is an example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfuugkw2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try event delegation:

```
 $(document).on("mouseenter", "#myTable tr", function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 1);
 });

 $(document).on("mouseleave", "#myTable tr", function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1);
 });
```

[Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Is there a particular reason for attaching it to `document` rather than something like  `$('#myTable').on("mouseenter", "tr", function() { ...`?

Comment: That's how i've always gotten stuff like this to work. Guess in this case you could go `$(document.body)...` or just `$("closestParent").on(...)`

Comment: Yeah.  I don't know either.  There could be speed differences either way, but I don't know enough of how jQuery operates in event delegation to say one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

To use a 'live' selection, use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

So like this:

```
$('body').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $( this ).animate({opacity: 0}, 1);
    }, mouseleave: function() {
        $( this ).animate({opacity: 1}, 1);
    }
},'#myTable tr');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using something like this:

`$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});`

Here's how it's applied in your code:

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {

   var newRow = '<tr><td>This is a dynamically added row.</td></tr>'; 
    $('#myTable').append(newRow);
});

$('#myTable').on( "mouseover", "tr", function () {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 1);
});

$('#myTable').on( "mouseout", "tr", function () {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfuugkw2/3/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a CSS3 transition for something like this. Simply add this to your CSS:

```
#myTable tr:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}
```

CSS is likely faster. See [Myth Busting: CSS Animations vs. JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/) for an overview of the pros/cons.